# Python different sized elements

Tags: python

I'm very new to python so I'm unsure about this. 
My ideal goal is to have a list that has the first element be a length of 30 composed of a random combination of 0/1's and also in that same list have elements 1-29 be a length of 5 composed of a random combination of 0/1's. Therefore, having a list that is 30 elements long. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this. I tried appending the 1-29 to the first element but that just made a longer list.

Ideally, I'd like it to look something similar to

list = [ 30 random zero/one's here, then 29 more elements with a length of 5 composed of random zero/one's]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Pck

Comment: What's wrong with ``x = ["0010100001","10101","10101", as long as you need]``?

Comment: I should have stated they needed to be random. I'll add that as an edit

Comment: Then [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle) them within each block after creating it like @Psytho suggested.

Comment: They need to be completely randomized. I was using np.random.randit (2, size =5,5) to get the random 0/1's and for that line giving a 5 rows with 5 elements in each.

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired output?

Comment: it would be something like [ 30 ones/zeros randomly populated, 29 more elements only being a length of 5 with elements that are either ones/zeros].

Comment: Please edit into the question an actual example as a valid python object. Right now we would just be guessing whether you want integers, strings, one list, list of list, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import random
result = [''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in range(30))]
for i in range(29):
    result.append(''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in range(5)))
```

The result is:

```
['110100110100110111100001100001', '01111', '01011', '10110',
'10101', '00011', '01010', '00110', '11000', '00111', '11001',
'00001', '11001', '00111', '00001', '10011', '11011', '01100',
'11001', '11001', '01100', '01101', '01010', '01111', '00111',
'01100', '10001', '11111', '01111', '01011']
```

The `''.join()` function joins an iterable of strings into a single string. `''` is the delimiter. If you prefer lists of integers, then use this code:

```
import random
result = [random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(30)]
for i in range(29):
    result.append([random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(5)])
```

Comment: Why do you think OP wants strings, in the comments they've used integer `0`,`1`. We should wait until the question is clear before answering.

Comment: I don't know this, i make assumptions. I also assume that we both hunt internet points by answering easy quesions. And that you downvote me because i was faster.

Comment: Are the number strings inside the list my understanding then? Also, could you explain your code a bit also, unsure what the .join stuff is really doing

Comment: @fafl Actually you weren't faster. I already had this answer written out, but I didn't post it because OPs question wasn't clear.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, now that I added information that I didn't know was really important at the beginning of asking the question, feel free to put your thoughts down as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really need this in a single data structure? I suggest splitting it out:

```
import numpy as np

elem0 = (np.random.rand(30)>0.5).astype(int)
elem1to29 = (np.random.rand(29,5)>0.5).astype(int)
```

now if you really want them in the same list you can combine them like this:

```
l = list(elem0)
l.extend(elem1to29)
```

which returns something like:

```
[array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1]), array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1]), array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0])]
```